# Finding if a user is verified in Icenium Everlive

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-mobile, icenium, everlive

I am new to Icenium Everlive and I am attempting to block logins by users who are not verified. My login and registration currently works using code like this:

```
function login() {
            var user = {
                "username": username.value,
                "password": password.value,
                "grant_type": "password"
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'https://api.everlive.com/v1/apikey/oauth/token',
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(user),
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    verifyUser()
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                    alert('Invalid Username or Password');
                }
            })            
        }
```

However when attempting to determine if a user is verified I am kind of failing. I keep getting a 404 request from the server when I ask it for the user using the API suggestion of:

```
   $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.everlive.com/v1/APIKEY/Users/me',
            type: "GET",
            headers: {"Authorization" : "Bearer ${AccessToken}"},
            success: function(data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        })
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Download and use the Everlive Javascript SDK:

https://www.everlive.com/AllApps/ManageApp/DownloadSDK

This wrapper will make things easier by forming and handling your AJAX requests.

(2) Then you can do something like this to login user and then check if verified:

```
function login(){

var applicationSettings = 
{emptyGuid: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', 
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'};     

//initialize everlive            
var _everlive = new Everlive({apiKey: applicationSettings.apiKey});

var currentUser = kendo.observable({ data: null });

//once instantiated, you can also use "Everlive.$" which 
//refs 1st created Everlive instance i.e.:  Everlive.$.Users.login(...)
_everlive.Users.login(username.value,password.value).then(function(){        

    return _everlive.Users.currentUser();
    })
.then(function(data){

        var currentUserData = data.result;
        currentUser.set('data', currentUserData);            
     })
.then(function(){            
      alert(currentUser.get("data.IsVerified"));  

},function(err){
      //handle error....  
});
```

}

Comment: Thanks mate, I was using the wrong SDK, duh! :P
The javascript SDK is much easier, although is there anyway to query the everlive db via attributes? like I would in a SQL DB?